# Function composition types not lining up

Tags: haskell

I'm having a bit of trouble with my types lining up in this code:

```
distance :: (Floating a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a
distance (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = sqrt $ (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2

gravitation :: (Num a, Floating a) => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> a
gravitation = ((**) (-1.0)) . ((**) 2.0) . distance
```

I was under the impression that since `distance` returns a `Floating` variables, I could pipe it into the `((**) 2.0)`.  Is there a fix for this whilst keeping the code relatively elegant?

The error I get is:

```
Main.hs:13:16:
    Could not deduce (Floating ((a, a) -> a))
      arising from a use of `**'
    from the context (Num a, Floating a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 gravitation :: (Num a, Floating a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a
      at Main.hs:12:16-57
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Floating ((a, a) -> a))
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `((**) (- 1.0))'
    In the expression: ((**) (- 1.0)) . ((**) 2.0) . distance
    In an equation for `gravitation':
```

Comment: A function of two arguments is really a function of one argument, returning another function of one argument.  The upshot is that `(.)` really only works to compose functions of one (remaining) argument; you can do tricks to get more but it gets more complex.

Comment: So is the issue that it's basically trying to pipe a function of type `(a,a) -> a` into `((**) 2.0)` instead of my desired double?

Comment: @Tombert correct.  Try doing `:t ((**) 2.0) . distance` in GHCi, it'll derive a type for you, but it'll be nonsensical with `Floating ((a, a) -> a)` as a constraint.  Try `:t (. distance)`, the type it'll return will be all sorts of crazy.  Then try `:t \x -> ((**) 2.0) . distance x`, the type will now make sense and look like you want it to.

Comment: @Tombert Remember, you can eta-reduce `f x = h $ g x` to `f = h . g`, but you can't reduce `f x y = h $ g x y` to `f x = h . g x` to `f = h . g`, since in the second example you reduce the `$` to `.` with the `y` parameter.  That's essentially what's happening here, and why a new combinator is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `distance` takes two arguments, you need a composition operator that works with two.  [There's a package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0) out there that has handy ones defined, but it's pretty easy to remember in a pinch:

```
infixr 9 .:
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(.:) = (.).(.)
```

Now you should be able to do

```
gravitation = (negate 1 **) . (2 **) .: distance
```

The `infixr 9` is important, it sets the fixity of the `.:` operator to be the same as the `.` operator.  I always just quickly check this in GHCi with `:i (.)` because who has time to remember these things?  Whenever I see this problem, I always like to point out that this operator has a more general form using `fmap`:

```
(.:) :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
(.:) = fmap fmap fmap
```

Technically, the first of those `fmap`s is for the function functor, so it's the same as `fmap . fmap` as well.  This more general form simply `fmap`s a function 2 layers deep, and in the case of functions being your functors it turns out to be this handy composition operator.  It has other uses, though:

```
(+1) .: [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
[Just 2, Nothing, Just 4]
```

Again, it just applies `(+1)` two functor layers deep, that's it.